# Update Classic ASP with ASP.net MVC or Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp-classic

We have an old web application developed in asp classic, its complicated application but now we need some changes and need to add extra page. I am a windows developer and never worked on web application. I see this as an opportunity to learn asp.net mvc or core, with time and budget constrain I can't rewrite whole thing but can I keep some portion in classic and rewrite some on asp core or mvc? Any other idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just keep in mind that the two technologies can't share things like session since classic ASP (not ASP.Net WebForms which some people also refer to as classic) is a much older technology. Moving to MVC or Core are both great moves, but you'll have a lot more to get used to coming from Windows development. Take small bites and don't try to do everything at once.

Comment: @Tseng if it ain't broke, and you can still support it, don't fix it. Big inert companies especially (or little ones with no resources) often stick to this mantra. If you think that's old, you should see the software that banks use, or NASA...again, if the stuff is still supportable, and it does the job, why not use it until you need something else. In this case the OP has been asked to support something they know nothing about, which is not ideal, and I understand the reluctance to learn a legacy technology with no big employment future. No-one writes _new_ stuff in ASP classic AFAIK.

Comment: Reason I was thinking to mix and match (classic and core) was time and budget but I guess that is not possible :(
Thanks all.